# Session management in Zend Framework 2

Tags: session, zend-framework2, zend-acl

Trying to do site with administration on Zend Framework 2, set the authorization at `mysite / admin / login`. How to deny access if the authorization is not completed all the way after `mysite / admin / ...`?

In ZF1 for this I used `«BaseController»`, but ZF2 want to check session in class Module.

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $sm = $app->getServiceManager();
        $config = $sm->get('Configuration');

        // DB Adapter
        $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);

        // Session
        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig, null, null);
        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
        $sessionManager->start();
    }
}
```

Tell me whether I want to do? And in which direction to look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [zend session and zend auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001847/zend-session-and-zend-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Zendframe Work 2 [EventManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html).

Comment: I don't think this comment is useful at all.